# QTransform Include conflict between QtGui and Qt3D

Tags: qt, qt5, qtgui, qt3d, qt5.15

I am using Qt 5.15.2 and the **qmake** build system for the project. I have included **Qt3D** by adding `Qt += 3dcore 3drender` in the `.pro` file.

When building the project, I get this error from `qgeoprojection_p.h`, line 121:

```
field 'm_itemToWindowTransform' has incomplete type 'QTransform'
```

As far as I know, the `qgeoprojection_p.h` file is having issues with resolving `#include <QTransform>` and its using the `QTransform` defined inside the **Qt3D** instead of the **GUI** component.

I have raised a [Qt bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-114562) for this.

How to get past this and use Qt3D in my project?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Qt provides different classes with the same name in different packages. To resolve this issue you need to explicitely specify which one you want to use, i.e. instead of doing

```
#include <QTransform>
```

you need to include the package path in the include command

```
#include <Qt3DCore/QTransform>
#include <QtGui/QTransform>
```

and use `Qt3DCore::QTransform` and `QtGui::QTransfrom` in your code.